# C# why am I getting the last index value during a method call?

Tags: c#

I am calling a method CalcGamma which returns a double value in my CalcResult. While debugging it calculates double value from each list. While I debug, I notice during the return statement in CalcGamma method, it returns and assigns the value of last index only. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public GammaCalcResult CalculateGamma(GammaCalcParam param)
{
    var resultPortfolios = new List<PortfolioOutputModel>();
    foreach (var portfolio in param.portfolios)
    {
        resultPortfolios.Add(new PortfolioOutputModel
        {
            portfolioIdentifier = portfolio.portfolioIdentifier,
            portfolioGamma = CalcGamma(param.portfolios, param.phases)
        });
    }

    return new GammaCalcResult
    {
        portfolios = resultPortfolios
    };
}

private double CalcGamma(List<PortfolioInputModel> portfolios, List<PhaseInputModel> phases)
{
    double currentGamma = 0.00;
    List<List<double>> intermediate_gamma_calc1 = gammaFunc(portfolios, phases);
    for (int i = 0; i < intermediate_gamma_calc1.Count; i++)
    {
        double val = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < intermediate_gamma_calc1[0].Count; j++)
        {
            val += (intermediate_gamma_calc1[i][j] * portfolios[i].gammaFactors[j].factorOffered);
        }
        val = val - portfolios[i].planFee - portfolios[i].advisoryFee;
        currentGamma = val;
    }
    return currentGamma;
}
```

Comment: portfolioGamma = CalcGamma(param.portfolios, param.phases) is what gets assigned the duplicated values instead of returning value from each iteration.

Comment: What should this code do? What does `gammaFunc` do?

Comment: Keeping things simple- it's supposed to return portid and a double value. gammFunc is what calculates a double value for each portid. It calculates for each portfolio but only returns last index value and assigns the last index to each portid.

Comment: You need to declare `double val = 0` out side the for loop. And move `currentGamma = val` should be after the for loop

Comment: that doesn't work.

Comment: That's because you are using the same parameters in the for loop to call this method. 
            `portfolioGamma = CalcGamma(param.portfolios, param.phases); `so you'll get the same result.

Comment: did anything work @MihirPatel ?

Comment: No. I still want to solve this problem. This solution returns the last index when the method is called  portfolioGamma = CalcGamma(param.portfolios, param.phases) for each portfolio. It makes sense because CalcGamma in foreach (var portfolio in param.portfolios) gets called three times but doesn't know which index. I just can't wrap my head around how to return currentGamma and assign it to each portfolio during the loop. @chetan-ranpariya

Comment: Your logic is not right. You are looping thru params.portfolios and you are passing the same list again and again to CalcGamma method? Why? That means you are passing the same input to the method 3 times to get the same results all 3 times. Why? `CalcGamma` method should perform calculation on list of portfolios and list of phases ? or it should be only one portfolio and one phase?

Comment: I got it. I am still trying to learn C# syntax. So that makes so much sense now. CalcMethod should be only ONE portfolio and phase.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I seriously dont know how I missed that. Passed in 1 portfolio in each method instead of passing all portfolios. And it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 0; j < intermediate_gamma_calc1[0].Count; j++)
```

should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < intermediate_gamma_calc1[i].Count; j++)
```

perhaps?

----------------------------------------above was not the answer------------------------------------

I guess this is the one then:

```
currentGamma = val;
```

should be

```
currentGamma += val;
```

Comment: This is not it still.